# Getting total amount of orders using sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi lets say i have the following tow tables

first table is `Orders` which consist of following columns

```
Order_ID  OrderDate
1          2016-01-20
2          2016-01-21
```

and the second table is `OrderDetails` which consist of following columns

```
Order_ID ProductID UnitPrice Quantity
1         1        5.00       1
1         3        20.00      3
2         2        10.00      2
```

How can i get the following out put

```
Order_ID  OrderDate    OrderTotalamount
 1        2016-01-20    65.00
 2        2016-01-21    20.00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you mind trying something like this out?

```
SELECT ORD.Order_ID, ORD.OrderDate, SUM(ORDD.UnitPrice * ORDD.Quanity) AS OrderTotalAmount

FROM Orders ORD

INNER JOIN OrderDetails ORDD
ON ORDD.Order_ID = ORD.Order_ID

GROUP BY ORD.Order_ID, ORD.OrderDate
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
SELECT a.Order_ID, a.OrderDate, SUM(Quantity*UnitPrice) as OrderTotalamout
  FROM Orders a JOIN OrderDetains ON (a.Order_ID = OrderDetails.Order_ID) 
 GROUP BY 1, 2;
```

I hope it works fine for you.

Comment: Too fast!  For my own edification @fmgonzalez what are the 1,2 at the end of the statement?  I am guessing it indicates group on 1st and 2nd item to select?

Comment: I prefer to use the column name as you probably change the order of your columns in the select statement in the future.

Comment: Yes, you guessed well. I'm used to this. Sorry if it looks obscure.

Comment: @sqluser I agree with you, even for easy reading is better add the column name. Anyway I only use this notation in short queries like this one, or when I have only a few fields in the select or columns names are too long.

Answer (score 1):

YOU CAN USE

```
SELECT TABLE1.Order_ID, TABLE1.OrderDate, SUM(TABLE2.Quantity*TABLE2.UnitPrice) as TotalPrice
  FROM TABLE1 JOIN TABLE2 WHERE(TABLE1.Order_ID = TABLE2.Order_ID);
```